# Possible to dump AJAX content from webpage?

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl

I would like to dump all the names on [this page](http://www.familiestyrelsen.dk/samliv/navne/soeginavnelister/godkendtefornavne/drengenavne/) and all the remaining 146 pages.

The red/orange previous/next buttons uses JavaScript it seams, and gets the names by AJAX.

**Question**

Is it possible to write a script to crawl the 146 pages and dump the names?

Does there exist Perl modules for this kind of thing?

Comment: You don't need to use AJAX. A simple POST request will do - see my updated answer.

Comment: Off-Topic: You might be interested in visiting http://act.yapc.eu/gpw2014 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) or another Crawler for this. [Web::Scraper](http://p3rl.org/Web%3a%3aScraper) might also be a good idea.

```
use Web::Scraper;
use URI;
use Data::Dump;

# First, create your scraper block
my $scraper = scraper {
    # grab the text nodes from all elements with class type_firstname (that way you could also classify them by type)
    process ".type_firstname", "list[]" => 'TEXT';
};

my @names;
foreach my $page ( 1 .. 146) {
  # Fetch the page (add page number param)
  my $res = $scraper->scrape( URI->new("http://www.familiestyrelsen.dk/samliv/navne/soeginavnelister/godkendtefornavne/drengenavne/?tx_lfnamelists_pi2[gotopage]=" . $page) );
  # add them to our list of names
  push @names, $_ for @{ $res->{list} };
}

dd \@names;
```

It will give you a very long list with all the names. Running it may take some time. Try with `1..1` first.

Answer (score 1):

In general, try using [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) which will essentially remote-control Firefox.

For that particular page though, you can just use something as simple as [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aTiny#post_form).

Just make POST requests to the URL and pass the parameter `tx_lfnamelists_pi2[gotopage]` from 1 to 146.

Example at http://hackst.com/#4sslc for page #30.

Moral of the story: always look in Chrome's Network tab and see what requests the web page makes.